# How to add a callback argument to an api

Tags: php, api, soap, slim

**Overview**

I am building an API which needs to allow for my server to essentially "push" new information to subscribers.  I haven't been able to find any tutorials or examples of how this sort of ability is actually implemented (calling an arbitrary per-user-defiend callback with arguments).

**Example**

For example, PayPal has a callback called "IPN" (Instant Payment Notification).  When a payment occurs on your account, PayPal calls this user-defined url of your choosing and passes it a bunch of data.

**Details**

I'm writing in PHP, storing to MySQL, and using Slim for routing, if that matters.

**Questions**

**1** Assuming arguments come in over POST, how should a callback argument be formatted?

For example, here is how I would get a `client_id` argument which was passed in to a route like `mysite.com/api/v1/setClientId`

```
global $app;
$json = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());
$client_id = $json->client_id;
```

I'd like to be able to say "add a `callback` parameter as a url string".  Would it be as simple as `client_id`?

**2** How can I get a stored callback string and call it?

I am certain this is not

```
header($callback_url);
```

**3** How can I pass data to this callback?  Assume I have the power to enforce a "standard" protocol on users of the API.

**4** Are there any gotchas like XSS prevention or any security concerns to watch for?  Like a dangerous URL being passed or called?

Strangely, this strikes me as pretty basic stuff, and considering how advanced some of my PHP has become, I'm surprised I haven't had to learn how to do this yet.  But, also curiously, I can't find any tutorials on the subject.  Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology.

*How can you add a "callback" function to a webservice (in PHP)?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPN and other notifications in payment gateways sends usual HTTP request to user's callback url. In PHP you can use [extension cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php).
Example with data: [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Usually, API gets callback url from predefined user's settings by client_id.